# Removing trailing comma sql

Tags: sql, sql-server

I know this has been posted a million times but I cannot figure out how to remove the trailiing comma in this example.  I don't want to make a new column I just want to go through each column, parse the comma deliminator list and print out these codes with their description.

For example, If the list is GLU, VEG then I want it to print:
Gluten free, Vegetarian.  However, I fwr "Gluten free, Vegetarian,"  Notice the comma at the very end.

Here is what I have currently:

```
SELECT *,
    CASE WHEN( RE.FOODOPTIONS LIKE '%GLU%') THEN 'Gluten free,'
                  WHEN( RE.FOODOPTIONS LIKE '%ALL%') THEN 'Food Allergies,'
                  WHEN( RE.FOODOPTIONS LIKE '%VEG%') THEN 'Vegetarian,'
                  WHEN( RE.FOODOPTIONS LIKE '%OTHER%') THEN 'Other,'
    END
FROM RegExt AS RE
```

Thanks.

**Sample data:**

```
FOODOPTIONS: GLU, ALL, VEG 
Results: Gluten free, Food Allergies, Vegetarian,
Desired Results: Gluten free, Food Allergies, Vegetarian

FOODOPTIONS: GLU
Results: Gluten free,
Desired Results: Gluten free

FOODOPTIONS: GLU, VEG 
Results: Gluten free, Vegetarian,
Desired Results: Gluten free, Vegetarian
```

The value of FOODOPTIONS is a list of codes separated by a comma.  It is able to make a list of them but includes the comma at the end.

Comment: I am using SQL Server.  Should have included that to start.

Comment: Do u expect to have both '%GLU%' and '%VEG%' in mapping ?

Comment: To expand on B House's question - CASE statements stop evaluating once they meet a 'true' condition. So a string like 'GLU, VEG' will only return 'Gluten Free' (as GLU is the first test condition in your CASE statement. Both answers so far (by Leonhard & Gordon) avoid this and will successfully parse a string of 'GLU, VEG'.

Comment: What's weird is that my original did parse it but it left the comma at the end as I had included it in the string.  I never thought to t double reverse it.  I was fixated on using SUBSTRING to remove the last character.  That was really smart and easy to understand!  Thanks for all of your responses!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use IIF, concatenate the strings and chop of the last character

```
SELECT *,
reverse(stuff(reverse(
    IIF(FOODOPTIONS LIKE '%GLU%', 'Gluten free,', '')+
    IIF(FOODOPTIONS LIKE '%ALL%', 'Food Allergies,', '')+
    IIF(FOODOPTIONS LIKE '%VEG%', 'Vegetarian,', '')+
    IIF(FOODOPTIONS LIKE '%OTHER%', 'Other,', '')
), 1, 1, ''))
FROM RegExt;
```

As you don't know the length of your string, you can reverse the string, chop of the first character and reverse it again.

Answer (score 2):

I do this using `stuff()`:

```
SELECT re.*,
       STUFF( (CASE WHEN RE.FOODOPTIONS LIKE '%GLU%' THEN ',Gluten free' ELSE '' END) +
               CASE WHEN RE.FOODOPTIONS LIKE '%ALL%' THEN ',Food Allergies' ELSE '' END) +
               CASE WHEN RE.FOODOPTIONS LIKE '%VEG%' THEN ',Vegetarian'  ELSE '' END) +
               CASE WHEN RE.FOODOPTIONS LIKE '%OTHER%' THEN ',Other'  ELSE '' END
              ), 2, LENGTH(RE.FOODOPTIONS), ''
             )
FROM RegExt AS RE
```

Answer (score 0):

You could probably use REPLACE three times?

```
DECLARE @FoodOptions varchar(100) = 'GLU, VEG'    
SELECT REPLACE( REPLACE( REPLACE (@FoodOptions, 'GLU', 'Gluten free'), 'ALL', 'Food Alergies'), 'VEG', 'Vegetarian') AS [ColumnName]
```

Gives output:

```
ColumnName
Gluten free, Vegetarian
```